# Out of memory Exception on Listview with images and inkcanvas UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

my idea is to create a listview with images, over each image I would like to insert a InkCanvas.
I tried two ways and both have problems.

**First way.**

I created the listview with its DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListViewItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
           <Image></Image>
           <InkCanvas></InkCanvas>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="ListItemsPanelTemplate">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection/>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<ListView x:Name="list" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}"
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ListItemsPanelTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

c#:

```
 List<Image> pages = new List<Image>();
    list.ItemsSource = pages;
```

In this way, the listview uses virtualization, when I write in a inkview, the stroke is copied every 5 inkview. It's not good.

If I remove the virtualization:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="ListItemsPanelTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

It occurs the problem of the second way. Written below.

**Second way:**

I created a usercontrol PageFormat for the DataTemplate like this:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid Background="White">
    <Image x:Name="image"></Image>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="ink" ></InkCanvas>
</Grid>
</UserControl>

<ListView x:Name="list" ></ListView>
```

c#:

```
List<PageFormat> pages= new List<PageFormat>();
list.ItemsSource = pages;
```

In this way I have the following problem:[like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407655/uwp-inkcanvas-out-of-memory)

When I create more than 125 InkCanvas I have a memory problem.
I prefer the second way because I can play with the formatting of the page directly in a usercontrol, but I can not solve these problems.

I would like to solve the problem of generating InkCanvas the System.OutOfMemoryException error.
How can I solve it?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Why you didn't use `ItemsStackPanel`?

Comment: instead of listview? however I think that reoccurs the problem of memory for more than 125 InkCanvas.

Comment: intead of StackPanel

Comment: Also, what the dimensions of Image in App and source image?

Comment: I only posted the elements without property, the application works, I view images, for less than 125 images has no problems, problems occur with too many images because it can not create more than 125 InkCanvas, and cause out of memory exception.

Comment: IF you put large image it will occurrs memory leak.

Comment: Nope there is no memory leak only an out of memory exception due to many inkcanvas.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure that `InkCanvas` is the cause of *out of memory* exceptions, you could do the following pseudo-system:

- when a user is not editing an item, it should be persisted to disk/memory and a bitmap rendered and presented out of it.
- when a user starts editing an item, de-serialize its data and realize it as an `InkCanvas`

i.e. use less resource-intensive types wherever it is appropriate

**EDIT**

Here's the solution to the fact that rendering an `InkCanvas` to a `RenderTargetBitmap` will produce a blank image:

https://mtaulty.com/2016/02/16/windows-10-uwp-inkcanvas-and-rendertargetbitmap/

(requires Win2D package)

Comment: could be a solution, I'll try.